# Create vertex group for selected points in grease pencil object

Tags: python, grease-pencil, vertex-groups

I know how to add VG for selection in mesh object, but not for gpencil...

````
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active

vert_indices = []

if obj.type == "MESH":
    vertices = obj.data.vertices

if obj.type == "GPENCIL":
    vertices = obj.data.points # <==== here is problem

for vert in vertices:
    if vert.select == True:
        index = vert.index
        vert_indices.append(index)

if obj.type == "MESH":
    print("creating vertex group for MESH")
    group = obj.vertex_groups.new(name=f"VG_MESH")
    group.add(vert_indices, 1.0, "REPLACE")

if obj.type == "GPENCIL":
    print("creating vertex group for GP")
    group = obj.vertex_groups.new(name=f"VG_GPENCIL")
    group.add(vert_indices, 1.0, "REPLACE")
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Grease pencil points are nested in a hierarchy in the API so you need to tunnel down to their python object to access them. They don't have an index attr so you need to get their index by enumerating the list. Also, it seems to complain about adding to the group in Edit mode, so I have it switching to OBJECT mode and then back to EDIT_GPENCIL...not so sure about that one, but I think this code does what you're looking for:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active

vert_indices = []

if obj.type == "MESH":
    vertices = obj.data.vertices

if obj.type == "GPENCIL":
    vertices = []
    gp = obj.data
    for layer in gp.layers:
        for frame in layer.frames:
            for stroke in frame.strokes:
                for point in stroke.points:
                    vertices.append(point)
                
for i, vert in enumerate(vertices):
    if vert.select == True:
        vert_indices.append(i)

if obj.type == "MESH":
    print("creating vertex group for MESH")
    group = obj.vertex_groups.new(name=f"VG_MESH")
    group.add(vert_indices, 1.0, "REPLACE")

if obj.type == "GPENCIL":
    print("creating vertex group for GP")
    group = obj.vertex_groups.new(name=f"VG_GPENCIL")
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
    group.add(vert_indices, 1.0, "REPLACE")
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT_GPENCIL', toggle=False)
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the tip with enumerate, but it doesn't seem to work. It look like script executes without errors, but after that points doesn't selects in VG panel by "Select" button.

Comment: Feature still not supported. https://developer.blender.org/T56280